# Laravel: getting a single value from a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm trying get a single value from MySQL database using laravel but the problem I'm getting an array . this is my query result in MySQL command line:

```
select groupName from users;
```

---

```
+-----------+
| groupName |
+-----------+
| Admin     |
+-----------+
```

my laravel function:

```
public static function PermitAddNewUser(){
    $username=Session::get('key');
    $data=DB::select("select groupName from users where username='$username';");
    return $data; 
}
```

expected $data value is a string with value= Admin

but what i get is : `[{"groupName":"Admin"}]`

Comment: That's the funny thing about databases, tables comprise of rows and columns, just like an array.... `if (!empty($data)) { return $data[0]->groupName; } return null;`

Comment: Now why are you using Eloquent, but not taking advantage of the benefits of an ORM, but simply writing queries as you would without an ORM?

Comment: `$data = DB::table('users')->where('username', $username)->pluck('groupName');`

Comment: @MarkBaker thank you very much it work fine like this return $data[0]->groupName;

Comment: @MarkBaker yes using the second way of using ORM also work fine ,you are awesome .

Comment: @MarkBaker What if i get undefined offset?? especially when i want to handle several columns. The error comes from the zero in $data[0]

Comment: @pathros - If you get that error, then it's because no records were returned by the database query

Comment: @pathros - but if you have a question to ask, ask it as a question; not as a comment on somebody else's 8 month old question

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Edit:

Sorry i forgot about `pluck()` as many have commented :
Easiest way is :

```
return DB::table('users')->where('username', $username)->pluck('groupName');
```

Which will directly return the only the first result for the requested row as a string.

Using the fluent query builder you will obtain an array anyway.
I mean The Query Builder has no idea how many rows will come back from that query.
Here is what you can do to do it a bit cleaner

```
$result = DB::table('users')->select('groupName')->where('username', $username)->first();
```

The `first()` tells the queryBuilder to return only one row so no array, so you can do :

```
return $result->groupName;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i know i edited the answer, i agree pluck() is the best in that case.

Comment: In Laravel 5.2+ `pluck()` will always return an array

Comment: in laravel 5.5  first() this is better to  get a single result . sothat we can user $result->firstname

Comment: For anyone who comes here for Laravel >=5.3, please see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41545516/6935763

Answer (score 97):

**yet another edit**: As of version **5.2** `pluck` is **not** deprecated anymore, it just got new behaviour (same as `lists` previously - see side-note below):

**edit**: As of version **5.1** `pluck` is deprecated, so start using `value` instead:

```
DB::table('users')->where('username', $username)->value('groupName');
```

---

```
// valid for L4 / L5.0 only
DB::table('users')->where('username', $username)->pluck('groupName');
```

this will return single value of `groupName` field of the first row found.

---

**SIDE NOTE reg. @TomasButeler comment**: As Laravel doesn't follow sensible versioning, there are sometimes cases like this. At the time of writing this answer we had `pluck` method to get SINGLE value from the query (Laravel 4.* & 5.0).

Then, with L5.1 `pluck` got deprecated and, instead, we got `value` method to replace it.

But to make it funny, `pluck` in fact was never gone. Instead it just got completely new behaviour and... deprecated `lists` method.. (L5.2) - that was caused by the inconsistency between Query Builder and Collection methods (in 5.1 `pluck` worked differently on the collection and query, that's the reason).

Comment: Great! And how do you check whether the value was found or not? Ah ok. I have tried with `isset()` ☺

Comment: The `pluck` method has not been deprecated; `lists`, which is an alias of it, on the other hand, has. Furthermore, `value` and `pluck` are not interchangeable -- `pluck` will return an array of the columns requested (with an optional key, if a second parameter is given) whereas `value` will provide the value of the first result returned by the query builder.

Comment: @TomasButeler that's true. If you're new to Laravel, then see the answer again with appropriate comments :) Laravel, while being soo cool, often doesn't stick to the own standards.

Comment: Very true :) Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 36):

As of Laravel >= 5.3, best way is to use **value**:

```
$groupName = \App\User::where('username',$username)->value('groupName');
```

or

```
use App\User;//at top of controller
$groupName = User::where('username',$username)->value('groupName');//inside controller function
```

Of course you have to create a model User for users table which is most efficient way to interact with database tables in Laravel.

Answer (score 8):

**[EDIT]**
The expected output of the `pluck` function has changed from Laravel 5.1 to 5.2. Hence why [it is marked as deprecated in 5.1](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L271)

[In Laravel 5.1](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_pluck), `pluck` gets a single column's value from the first result of a query.

[In Laravel 5.2](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_pluck), `pluck` gets an array with the values of a given column. So it's no longer deprecated, but it no longer do what it used to.

So short answer is use the `value` function if you want one column from the first row and you are using Laravel 5.1 or above.

Thanks to Tomas Buteler for pointing this out in the comments.

**[ORIGINAL]**
For anyone coming across this question who is using Laravel 5.1, [pluck() has been deprecated](http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.0) and will be removed completely in Laravel 5.2.

Consider future proofing your code by using `value()` instead.

```
return DB::table('users')->where('username', $username)->value('groupName');
```

Comment: `pluck` has not been deprecated! `lists` was deprecated in Laravel 5.2 and will be removed in a later release, but `pluck` will hopefully live on for a good while.

Comment: @TomasButeler Thanks for pointing out that Laravel has repurpose the `pluck` function. I've updated my answer with extra details about the differences between the `pluck` function in 5.1 and 5.2.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it's quite clear now. Such a shame the updates from 5.1 to 5.2 where so confusing...

Answer (score 6):

Using query builder, get the single column value such as **groupName**

```
  $groupName = DB::table('users')->where('username', $username)->pluck('groupName');
```

For Laravel 5.1

```
 $groupName=DB::table('users')->where('username', $username)->value('groupName');
```

Or, Using user model, get the single column value

```
 $groupName = User::where('username', $username)->pluck('groupName');
```

Or, get the first row and then split for getting single column value

```
 $data = User::where('username', $username)->first();
 if($data)
   $groupName=$data->groupName;
```

Answer (score 6):

Continuing, here is how you do it in Laravel **7.x** or **8.x**

```
$email = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->value('email');
```

source: [trust me](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-single-row-column-from-a-table)

---

Updated based on @Shuhad zaman comment

Comment: Works with Laravel 7x as well.

Answer (score 4):

On laravel 5.6 it has a very simple solution:

```
User::where('username', $username)->first()->groupName;
```

It will return **groupName** as a string.

Comment: Perhaps, but it'll still instantiate the user. Using `->value('groupName')` should do a `SELECT groupname FROM` and return the string directly instead of retrieving all the user info and creating a user object.

Comment: Yes, I think ->value('groupName') is the better way to do that.