# Getting a single value from DB::select in Laravel 7.x

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel's `DB::select` to run a query to get a `MAX()` value. I only want the single column value from the single row result. What method do I use to get this from a `DB::select()` statement?

I found this answer[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25931022/151841) that proffered both `pluck()` and `value()`. The behavior of `pluck()` had changed since 5.3, so that wasn't the answer. However, when I used `value()`, I didn't get the value I was expecting. Instead I got an error about an array:

```
$query =  DB::select('SELECT max(sort) AS sort FROM man_pos WHERE manual_id = ?', [$manual_id]);
dd($query);
```

---

> Error HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
>
> Call to a member function value() on array

Of course, I can traverse the array to pull the value, but the whole point of using a method is to avoid such extra rigamarole.

---

Per a request in the comments, here is some sample data and expected result. First, the query:

```
MariaDB [dev]> SELECT MAX(sort) FROM man_pos WHERE manual_id = 1;
+-----------+
| MAX(sort) |
+-----------+
|         3 |
+-----------+
```

Second, what I would like to get:

```
$max_sort = DB::select('SELECT max(sort) AS sort FROM man_pos WHERE manual_id = ?', [$manual_id])->getSingleValue();

dd($max_sort);
```

---

```
^ 3
```

Comment: can you write sample data and expected data

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov Please see edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just try using Laravel's built in `MAX` function:

```
$max_sort = DB::table('man_pos')
    ->where('manual_id', $manual_id)
    ->max('sort');
```

Answer (score 0):

you want single column for single max return single value

```
$max_sort = DB::table('man_pos')->select('sort')->where('manual_id', '=', $manual_id)->max('sort');
```

Comment: @user151841 I just tested i was mistake you dont need get() and first() when you are using max() i edited answer did you try Tim Biegelesion answer it shoud be works